# Finding external Window's position?

Tags: windows, delphi, window-handles

How can I find the Screen-relative position of a Window Handle in Delphi? (X,Y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use FindWindow() to retrieve the handle of the window and and GetWindowRect() to get the coordinates:

```
var 
 NotepadHandle: hwnd;
 WindowRect: TRect;
begin
 NotepadHandle := FindWindow(nil, 'Untitled - Notepad');

 if NotepadHandle <> 0 then
   GetWindowRect(NotepadHandle, WindowRect)

end;
```

Answer (score 5):

try using the [`GetWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

```
var
  lpRect: TRect;
begin
   GetWindowRect(Edit1.Handle,lpRect);  
   ShowMessage(Format('%d,%d',[lpRect.Left,lpRect.Top]));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind, if the window(app) is minimized, you will get some values for the Rect like these `(-32000, -32000, -31840, -31972, (-32000, -32000), (-31840, -31972))`